# C- What is the matter of my mergesort algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, runtime-error, mergesort

I made a code of mergesort algorithm that have two inputs: the number of digits, and digits

And I want to print array sorted by my mergesort function.

But only i can see is **run time error**.

I think my **Merge()** function made runtime error. but I cant find the **exception** of my while loop in Merge function..

How can I fix this error and run mergesort function properly?

Here is my code

```
 #include <stdio.h>

void Merge(int *arr, int s, int e, int m);
void MergeSort(int *arr, int s, int e);

int main(void) {
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int arr[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    MergeSort(arr, 0, N - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
}

void MergeSort(int *arr, int s, int e) {
    printf("hi\n");
    int m;
    if (e - s > 0) {
        m = (s + e) / 2;
        MergeSort(arr, s, m);
        MergeSort(arr, m + 1, e);
        Merge(arr, s, e, m);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

void Merge(int *arr, int s, int e, int m) {
    int arr_t[e - s + 1];
    int i = s, j = m + 1, idx = s;
    while (1) {
        if (i != m && j != s) {
            if (i <= m && arr[i] <= arr[j]) {
                arr_t[idx] = arr[i];
                i++;
                idx++;
            } else
            if (j <= e) {
                arr_t[idx] = arr[j];
                j++;
                idx++;
            }
        } else
        if (i == m && j != e) {
            arr_t[idx] = arr[j];
            j++;
            idx++;
        } else
        if (i != m && j == e) {
            arr_t[idx] = arr[i];
            i++;
            idx++;
        } else {
            if (arr[i] <= arr[j]) { 
                arr_t[idx] = arr[i];
                idx++;
                arr_t[idx] = arr[j];
            } else {
                arr_t[idx] = arr[j];
                idx++;
                arr_t[idx] = arr[i];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int k = s; k <= e; k++) {
        arr[k] = arr_t[k];
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably going out of bounds of one of your arrays. Please learn how to use a debugger to catch run-time errors (*crashes*) to locate where they happen in your code, and also to examine the values of all involved variables (and indexes) at the point and time of the crash.

Comment: There are any segmentation fault error, nevertheless there can be going out of bounds of one of my arrays?

Comment: C has no bounds-checking. It's your responsibility to not go out of bounds.

Comment: Your temporary array `int arr_t[e - s + 1]` starts at index 0, like all other arrays, but you access elements `s` throuigh `e`, wich will be out of bounds for many arrays. (In general, I think you should use the typical C notation of _inclusive_ lower bound and _exclusive_ upper bound. I don't think that `j == e` and `j != e` do what you want in your current notation.)

Comment: You shouldn't append two values to the temporary array in your last `else` clause either: When both subarrays are exhausted, there's nothing more to do than just `break` the loop.

Comment: have you tried debugging yet? What where your findings? Please provide  the small failing example you debugged with.

Comment: `(j!=s)` in `Merge()`` looks funky to me.  But you will not regret learning how to use the debugger !  FWIW: this might all look simpler if the `while(1)` where `while ((i<=m) && (j<=e))` -- loop until the merge runs out of one or both parts.  Then deal with what remains in the not empty part.  Then copy the result back.  Also FWIW: for divide-and-conquer algorithms, there comes a point where there's no point recursing -- in this case, when you have just two elements, it would be trivial to do that "by hand" in `MergeSort()`.  Doing up to three elements in `MergeSort()` simplifies `Merge()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your part of code may be due to:

You are probably going out of bounds of one of your array as stated by @Some programmer dude

Instead of `while(1)` you may use `while(i<=mid && j<=end)` which loops until the merge runs out of one or both parts

N even instead of using so many else if in your merge function, you can use `while()` loop that will simplify your code.You shouldn't append two values to the temporary array in your last else clause either

Even `if(i!=m && j!=s)` this condition in your code looks a bit weird.

So I wrote this sample mergesort for your reference. Hope this helps!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
void merge(int a[],int start,int mid,int end){
int i=start,j=mid+1,k=0;
int temp[end-start+1];
while(i<=mid && j<=end){
    if(a[i]<a[j]){
        temp[k]=a[i];
        k+=1;
        i+=1;
    }
    else{
        temp[k]=a[j];
        k+=1;
        j+=1;
    }
}
while(i<=mid){
    temp[k]=a[i];
    i+=1;k+=1;
}
while(j<=end){
    temp[k]=a[j];
    j+=1;k+=1;
}
for(int i=end;i>=start;i--){
    a[i]=temp[--k];
}


}



void mergesort(int a[],int start,int end){
if(start<end){
int mid=(start+end)/2;
mergesort(a,start,mid);
mergesort(a,mid+1,end);
merge(a,start,mid,end);

}
}



void display(int a[],int n){
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
printf("%d ",a[i]);

}



int main()

{
    int a[5]={5,4,6,2,1};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    mergesort(a,0,n-1);
    display(a,n);
}
```

With the worst-case time complexity being `Ο(n log n)`

Comment: @jsjclink are you now able to resolve your issue??

Comment: Wow the code is very very helpful!!! Thank you so much:) i have to reduce my too many **else if**!! Due to your advice, not only i could solve my problem of my code but also got a  great tip of coding! Thank you :)

Comment: @jsjclink can you please accept and upvote my answer, if it worked for u :)

Comment: @jsjclink If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left.